# CS50 - filter (more comfortable) Edges - only blue value is wrong

Tags: c, image-processing, cs50, edge-detection

I had a problem when I was trying to solve the edge detection problem in the [CS50](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2021/psets/4/filter/more/).

Below is my code:

```c
        // Detect edges
    void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
    {
        // Ask for some temparory memories for store blur pixels
         RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];
         
         // Consider every condition you may encounter with pixels
        int GxR, GyR, GxG, GyG, GxB, GyB;
        
        // Initialize Gx and Gy metrix
        int Gx[3][3] = {{-1, 0, 1}, {-2, 0, 2}, {-1, 0, 1}};
        int Gy[3][3] = {{-1, -2, -1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}};
        
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                GxR = GyR = GxG = GyG = GxB = GyB= 0;
    
                // Loop over 3x3 pixels
                for (int h = -1; h < 2; h++)
                {
                    for (int w = -1; w < 2; w++)
                    {
                        // Check if this pixel is outside the image
                        if (i + h < 0 || i + h > height - 1)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        
                        if (j + w < 0 || j + w > width - 1)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        
                        // sum each channel value
                        // X
                        GxR += image[i + h][j + w].rgbtRed * Gx[h + 1][w + 1];
                        GxG += image[i + h][j + w].rgbtGreen * Gx[h + 1][w + 1];
                        GxB += image[i + h][j + w].rgbtBlue * Gx[h + 1][w + 1];
                        
                        // Y
                        GyR += image[i + h][j + w].rgbtRed * Gy[h + 1][w + 1];
                        GyG += image[i + h][j + w].rgbtGreen * Gy[h + 1][w + 1];
                        GyB += image[i + h][j + w].rgbtBlue * Gy[h + 1][w + 1];
                    }
                }
                
                // Calculate every Gx and Gy value and store in temp
                temp[i][j].rgbtRed = round(sqrt((GxR * GxR  + GyR * GyR)));
                temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(sqrt((GxG * GxG + GyG * GyG)));
                temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(sqrt((GxB * GxB + GyB * GyB)));
                
                // Capped color value at 255
                if (temp[i][j].rgbtRed > 255)
                {
                    temp[i][j].rgbtRed = 255;
                }
                
                if (temp[i][j].rgbtGreen > 255)
                {
                    temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = 255;
                }
                
                if (temp[i][j].rgbtBlue > 255)
                {
                    temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = 255;
                }
            }
        }       
    
        // Ready to iterate whole image from temp to image[i][j]
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                image[i][j] = temp[i][j];
            }
        }
        
        return;
    }
```

And when I ran check50, the result shows that the pixels' red and green values are correct but only blue is wrong. The result is as below:

```
    :( edges correctly filters pixel on edge
        expected "213 228 255\n", not "213 228 140\n"
    :( edges correctly filters pixel in corner
        expected "76 117 255\n", not "76 117 66\n"
    :( edges correctly filters 3x3 image
        expected "76 117 255\n21...", not "76 117 66\n213..."
    :( edges correctly filters 4x4 image
        expected "76 117 255\n21...", not "76 117 66\n213..."
```

Can somebody tell me what's wrong with my code?
I've tried my best to debug it but I still can't find where went wrong...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you checked the other pixels? Maybe only for the first pixel R and G are correct and for the other pixels there are more errors.

Comment: Also, the test results normally contain more details about the test. You could look at the input data and feed them into your function. Then execute it step by step in your debugger and compare values with the values you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `edges` function is almost correct. You just missed that with

```
                // Calculate every Gx and Gy value and store in temp
                temp[i][j].rgbtRed = round(sqrt((GxR * GxR  + GyR * GyR)));
                temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(sqrt((GxG * GxG + GyG * GyG)));
                temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(sqrt((GxB * GxB + GyB * GyB)));
```

the members `rgbtRed`, `rgbtGreen` and `rgbtBlue` are only 8 bits and the behavior of assigning floating type values from 256 on to them is undefined; the following code to cap the values can't work. So cap the RGB values before assigning them:

```
                temp[i][j].rgbtRed   = fmin(round(sqrt(GxR * GxR + GyR * GyR)), 255);
                temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = fmin(round(sqrt(GxG * GxG + GyG * GyG)), 255);
                temp[i][j].rgbtBlue  = fmin(round(sqrt(GxB * GxB + GyB * GyB)), 255);
```

Comment: I totally forgot to check the type of value. After I took your advice the program ran just correctly.
Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was able to finally solved my problem in this PSET after realizing to make the Gx and Gy as 2D arrays. I originally declared them as 1D array and getting into trouble in getting the exact position of the gx pixel. Moreover, mine did not need to use fmin function and also I noticed that you are filtering a temp image and then applying the filter of each pixel of the temp image to the original image. For me, I just created a copy of the original image and took it as a reference for the original values. Here's my code.

```
// Detect edges
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // Declare a variable to store copy the copy of the image
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
    // Gx and Gy constants
    int gx[3][3] = {{-1, 0, 1}, {-2, 0, 2}, {-1, 0, 1}};
    int gy[3][3] = {{-1, -2, -1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}};

    // Creates a copy of the image
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            copy[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }

    // Loops through each row in the image
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        // Loops through each column in the iterated row
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            // Initialize gx & gy values for each channel
            double gx_red = 0, gx_green = 0, gx_blue = 0;
            double gy_red = 0, gy_green = 0, gy_blue = 0;

            // Iteration thru all the pixels in a 3x3 grid
            for (int row = -1; row < 2; row++)
            {
                for (int col = -1; col < 2; col++)
                {
                    // Checks for bounds
                    if (row + i < 0 || row + i > height - 1 || col + j < 0 || col + j > width - 1)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    gx_red += copy[i + row][j + col].rgbtRed * gx[row + 1][col + 1];
                    gx_green += copy[i + row][j + col].rgbtGreen * gx[row + 1][col + 1];
                    gx_blue += copy[i + row][j + col].rgbtBlue * gx[row + 1][col + 1];
                    
                    gy_red += copy[i + row][j + col].rgbtRed * gy[row + 1][col + 1];
                    gy_green += copy[i + row][j + col].rgbtGreen * gy[row + 1][col + 1];
                    gy_blue += copy[i + row][j + col].rgbtBlue * gy[row + 1][col + 1];
                }
            }
            // square root of gx^2 + gy^2

            double sobel_red = sqrt(((gx_red * gx_red) + (gy_red * gy_red)));
            double sobel_green = sqrt(((gx_green * gx_green) + (gy_green * gy_green)));
            double sobel_blue = sqrt(((gx_blue * gx_blue) + (gy_blue * gy_blue)));

            if (sobel_red > 255)
            {
                sobel_red = 255;
            }
            if (sobel_green > 255)
            {
                sobel_green = 255;
            }
            if (sobel_blue > 255)
            {
                sobel_blue = 255;
            }

            image[i][j].rgbtRed = (int) round(sobel_red);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = (int) round(sobel_green);
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = (int) round(sobel_blue);
        }
    }   

    return;
}
```